# Android Recyclerview with multiple ViewTypes not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I created a Recyclerview that has two different view types. One for when the list is empty and one for when there is data in the list. From what I see in the logs, the only method that is getting called is getItemCount(). I can't figure out why that is the only method getting called or what I am doing wrong. Below is my code.

empty_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="No Goals Added"
    android:textColor="#525252"
    android:textSize="19sp" />
```

content_goals.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/goals_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    />
```

GoalsActivity.java

```
GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView goalsListView;
....

goalsListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.goals_list);

....

 private void createGoalsList() {
    //set array adapter for the goals list
    adapter = new GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter(new ArrayList<Goal>());
    goalsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
public class GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

List<Goal> mGoals;
private final int EMPTY=0, GOAL=1;

public GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Goal> goals) {
    Log.d(TAG, "adapter initialized");
    mGoals = goals;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.goal_row, parent, false);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: inside");
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view, parent, false);

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: viewType" + viewType);

    switch (viewType){
        case EMPTY:
            viewHolder = new EmptyViewHolder(emptyView);
        break;
        case GOAL:
            View goalsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.goal_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new GoalsViewHolder(goalsView);
            break;
        default:
            viewHolder = new EmptyViewHolder(emptyView);
            break;
    }

    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: inside");
    EmptyViewHolder emptyViewHolder= (EmptyViewHolder) holder;

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case GOAL:
            GoalsViewHolder goalsViewHolder = (GoalsViewHolder) holder;
            goalsViewHolder.bind(goalsViewHolder, position);
            break;
        case EMPTY:
            emptyViewHolder.bind(emptyViewHolder, position);
            break;
        default:
            emptyViewHolder.bind(emptyViewHolder, position);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    Log.d(TAG, "getItemViewType: inside");

    if(mGoals.size()== EMPTY){
        return EMPTY;
    }else{
        return GOAL;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: " + mGoals.size());
    return mGoals.size();
}

public class GoalsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView goalsLabel, goalCount;
    public GoalsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        goalsLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.calls_goal_label);
        goalCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.goal_count);
    }

    public void bind(GoalsViewHolder vh, int position){
        Goal goal = mGoals.get(position);
        vh.goalsLabel.setText(goal.getGoalTitle());
        vh.goalCount.setText(goal.getGoalFrequency());
    }
}

public class EmptyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView emptyTextView;
    public EmptyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        emptyTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emptyElement);
    }

    public void bind(EmptyViewHolder vh, int position){

        vh.emptyTextView.setText("No Goals Added");
    }
}
```

Logs

```
09-18 20:09:09.990 26382-26382/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: adapter initialized
09-18 20:09:10.020 896-947/? D/StatusBarManagerService: disable:userId=0 what=0x0 which=0x1 pkg=Window{8a95441 u0 com.ubcma.leadster/com.ubcma.leadster.activity.GoalsActivity}
09-18 20:09:10.040 26382-26382/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: getItemCount: 0
09-18 20:09:10.050 26382-26382/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: getItemCount: 0
09-18 20:09:10.090 896-1002/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.ubcma.leadster/.activity.GoalsActivity: +202ms
09-18 20:09:10.100 26382-26382/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: getItemCount: 0
09-18 20:09:10.100 26382-26382/com.ubcma.leadster D/GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter: getItemCount:
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing?

Comment: @VASS_Tech The only method getting called in the adapter is getItemCount no other method is getting called besides the constructor so my screen doesn't display the empty_view.xml it is just blank.

Comment: I don't think that what you are trying to do will work. As long as getItemCount() returns 0, the other RecyclerView methods won't get called, because _the RecyclerView doesn't have any items to display._ No ViewHolders to create, no view types to check, no data to bind. @VASS_Tech has provided a practical way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: ok, wow. I didn't know that part. thank you @RapunzelVanWinkle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go for two xml layouts. keep it single use with the visibility. I have shown below the sample make use of it. It will definitely work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/goals_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/emptyElement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="No Goals Added"
    android:textColor="#525252"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then change your GoalsActivity.java as like below

```
GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView goalsListView;
TextView noGoalsTxt;
....

goalsListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.goals_list);
noGoalsTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyElement);
....

 private void createGoalsList() {
    //check your goals list is empty or not
     if(Goal!=null && Goal.size()>0{
    //set array adapter for the goals list
   goalsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    noGoalsTxt..setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter = new GoalsRecyclerViewAdapter(new ArrayList<Goal>());
    goalsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }else{
           goalsListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    noGoalsTxt..setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @VASS_Tech for your quick response but my goal is to understand how to use view types in order to learn how recyclerview works using multiple view types. Is there any reason why this approach wouldn't work using view types with recyclerview? Does recyclerview have an issue with empty lists?

Comment: Yes, recyclerview doesn't call for empty list. You have to maintain it without adapter itself.

Comment: I will make the changes you suggested and accept your answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

i tried a moment ago  .   The problem lies in Method getItemCount .if list.size==0, then will return 0,so will be not displayed

Comment: @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: " + mGoals.size());
        return 1;
    }